# Drone CI/CD has Login Failed. Invalid Response on my VM

Tags: nginx, devops, bitbucket-server, drone.io

I have an error when I am trying to start my Drone server with Bitbucket Server.

I have one VM with Centos7 with nginx. I started my bitbucket server with docker on 127.0.0.1:7990 and configure nginx for proxy pass on it.

```
server {
    server_name bitbucket.somniumgame.com;

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent = "") { return 404; }

        if ($limit_bots = 1) { return 404; }

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7990;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_redirect      off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bitbucket.somniumgame.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bitbucket.somniumgame.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = bitbucket.somniumgame.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name bitbucket.somniumgame.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

It works great and successful integrated with Jira Server which configured same by proxy.
Next, I am trying to integrate Drone CI/CD with this Bitbucket Sever.
I using them documentation https://docs.drone.io/server/provider/bitbucket-server/, but it didnt work for me.

I am starting  drone docker with

```
docker run \
  --volume=/var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone:z \
  --volume=/etc/bitbucket/key.pem:/etc/bitbucket/key.pem \
  --env=DRONE_GIT_PASSWORD=<user_password> \
  --env=DRONE_GIT_USERNAME=<user_name> \
  --env=DRONE_GIT_ALWAYS_AUTH=false \
  --env=DRONE_STASH_SERVER=https://bitbucket.somniumgame.com/ \
  --env=DRONE_STASH_CONSUMER_KEY=OauthKey \
  --env=DRONE_STASH_PRIVATE_KEY=/etc/bitbucket/key.pem \
  --env=DRONE_SERVER_HOST=drone.somniumgame.com \
  --env=DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=https \
  --env=DRONE_RPC_SECRET=<shared_secret_generated_by: openssl rand -hex 16> \
  --env=DRONE_LOGS_DEBUG=true \
  --env=DRONE_LOGS_TEXT=true \
  --env=DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY=true \
  --env=DRONE_LOGS_COLOR=true \
  --publish=127.0.0.1:8090:80 \
  --publish=127.0.0.1:8091:443 \
  --restart=always \
  --detach=true \
  --name=drone \
  drone/drone:1
```

On bitbucket server I created user with default permission for drone (without server admin privilege). And complete 1 step from https://docs.drone.io/server/provider/bitbucket-server/ .
But nowhere I using Personal Access Token.
My configurations look like this:

**Application Details**

```
Application Name: Drone
Application Type: Generic Application
Application URL: https://drone.somniumgame.com
Display URL: https://drone.somniumgame.com
```

**Outgoing Authentication**

```
Service Provider Name: Drone
Consumer Key: OauthKey
Shared Secret: <shared_secret_generated_by: openssl rand -hex 16>
Request Token URL: /
Access Token URL: /
Authorize URL: /
```

**Incoming Authentication**

```
Consumer Key: OauthKey
Consumer Name: Drone
Public Key: <generated_in_/etc/bitbucket/key.pub> 
Consumer Callback URL: None
Allow 2-Legged OAuth: false
Execute as: None
```

My docker logs for drone:

```
DEBU[0000] main: creating the Stash client               server="https://bitbucket.somniumgame.com/" skip_verify=false
INFO[0000] main: internal scheduler enabled
DEBU[0000] main: license loaded                          build.limit=5000 expires="0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC" kind=trial repo.limit=0 user.limit=0
INFO[0000] starting the cron scheduler                   interval=30m0s
INFO[0000] starting the http server                      acme=false host=drone.somniumgame.com port=":80" proto=https url="https://drone.somniumgame.com"
INFO[0000] starting the zombie build reaper              interval=24h0m0s
```

I cant understand why 80 port, if I used https proto?

My nginx configuration for drone:

```
server {
    server_name drone.somniumgame.com;

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent = "") { return 404; }

        if ($limit_bots = 1) { return 404; }

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_redirect      off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/drone.somniumgame.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/drone.somniumgame.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = drone.somniumgame.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name drone.somniumgame.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When I am trying to open https://drone.somniumgame.com/ , I had Login Failed. Invalid Response.
And logs looks like this after this:

```
DEBU[0301]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:18Z" latency="692.791µs" method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48352" request=/ request-id=1o9PsMWwAnQc8hOwfVIQNUPoECw
DEBU[0302] api: authentication required                  request-id=1o9PsMaQk8cpmlnMRw1BN0y6Itb
DEBU[0302] api: guest access                             request-id=1o9PsMaQk8cpmlnMRw1BN0y6Itb
DEBU[0302]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:18Z" latency="190.226µs" method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48356" request=/api/user request-id=1o9PsMaQk8cpmlnMRw1BN0y6Itb
DEBU[0302] events: stream opened                         request-id=1o9PsLGMLljP8KYN1wUh3fSvXRr
DEBU[0307] cannot authenticate user: Invalid Response
DEBU[0307]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:23Z" latency=5.045881375s method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48364" request=/login request-id=1o9PsMBp3ycu8U0FnUkuLTcm2rj
DEBU[0307]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:23Z" latency="130.637µs" method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48370" request="/login/error?message=Invalid%20Response" request-id=1o9Pt130Alm3Jt9sRnAHiEYssuN
DEBU[0307] events: stream cancelled                      request-id=1o9PsLGMLljP8KYN1wUh3fSvXRr
DEBU[0307] events: stream closed                         request-id=1o9PsLGMLljP8KYN1wUh3fSvXRr
DEBU[0307] api: guest access                             request-id=1o9PsLGMLljP8KYN1wUh3fSvXRr
DEBU[0307]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:23Z" latency=5.187463046s method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48360" request=/api/stream request-id=1o9PsLGMLljP8KYN1wUh3fSvXRr
DEBU[0307] api: authentication required                  request-id=1o9PtBl2zOctBOLf1KUtbwgPdqj
DEBU[0307] api: guest access                             request-id=1o9PtBl2zOctBOLf1KUtbwgPdqj
DEBU[0307]                                               fields.time="2021-02-07T11:07:24Z" latency="121.613µs" method=GET remote="172.17.0.1:48374" request=/api/user request-id=1o9PtBl2zOctBOLf1KUtbwgPdqj
DEBU[0307] events: stream opened                         request-id=1o9Pt8hxtXtKfe3YMxYXkTVMJ9d
```

Comment: Same issue, have you managed to solve it?

Comment: @Raz Luvaton, unfortunately, no

Comment: any update on this?, I'm seeing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. I had to delete the application link on bitbucket and recreate it to fix this issue, also,
2. I have deleted other drone application links using the same public key.

(2) might not be required